# Android Management Api losing control over enrolled device

Tags: device-policy-manager, android-management-api, android-enterprise

We are using android management API to manage our internal enterprise-level devices, it seems that sometimes google is losing the connectivity or command with the devices even if the device’s WIFI is fully functional.

We experienced that one of our enrolled devices on device patch to change the policy was not updating the lastPolicySyncTime(Displaying lastPolicySyncTime as 7th October but should have been the latest date when the device patch was performed) at google device JSON.

Therefore we tried Issuing REBOOT command on the device as we thought reboot can solve our problem even that seemed not to work and the device was not rebooting so we did a manual reboot and that updated the lastPolicySyncTime once to 24th October (was right for that day).

However, right now the device is still not updated with the latest lastPolicySyncTime(i.e. 26th October as of today) my understanding being google pings the device every day and lastpolicySycTime updates parallel. Also, it is a case with many devices I have mentioned one of them.

We are not facing any issue updating the device or policy configuration using android management API but the issue resides with google updating enrolled devices on any operation.

So I would like to ask you some questions on the above reference,

When does google pings the enrolled devices, is there some kind of scheduler running or is it only if we do a patch operation on the device or enrolled policy?

Why are we not able to get a reflection of operations(policy patch, issue command, and device patch) on devices at times?

Comment: We're experiencing the same problem. Sometimes after setting new policy on Device with devices().patch command I can see new policy set in Device's JSON, though it still has an old policy in "appliedPolicy" property. Seems, it's the same issue with DPC not checking updates.

Answer (score 0):

Device does periodically ping backend to see if there's a latest policy available.

Check if lastStatusReportTime / lastPolicyComplianceReportTime are being updated?

Comment: No timings are getting updated only gets updated on the device reboot and I don't think that's a good way. any help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was also caused by GCM issues and it is already fixed since February.